# Find all solutions $x \mapsto y$ of the equation $Dy - \frac{1}{x}\cdot y = x\sin x$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

By $Dy$ I mean the derivative of a function $x \mapsto y$ at a point $x$ in its domain.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Given the initial condition $y\big|_{x = a} = b,$ if the functions $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ and $x \mapsto x\sin x$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then the solution $x \mapsto y$ of the equation under consideration uniquely exists and takes the form
$$y = be^{-A(x)} + e^{-A(x)}\int_{a}^{x}t\sin t\cdot e^{A(t)} dt,$$
where $A(x) := \int_{a}^{x}\frac{1}{t} dt.$

However, since the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous at $x = 0,$ how may we solve the equation of interest for $x \mapsto y$ on $\mathbb{R}$? Am I understanding the question right?

Comment: There is a unique solution on each connected interval $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. But there is not a unique solution on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner: Thanks very much. Would you like to write an augmented answer?

Comment: Note that you can simplify your equation to $$D(y/x)=\sin(x).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniqueness theorem for 1st order linear IVP only holds on connected intervals. For instance, suppose $a > 0$, and let $f$ be the unique solution to the IVP on $(0, \infty)$ and let $g$ be an arbitrary solution to the ODE. Then
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if $x > 0$} \\ g(x) & \text{if $x < 0$} \end{cases}
$$
is a solution to the IVP, so clearly uniqueness doesn't hold.